# Is asterisk in pointer declaration an operator?

Tags: c++

I always thought that operators appear in expressions. But [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723823) seems to suggest that the asterisk in the declaration `int *p;` is an operator. Is this correct? If not, how is this asterisk called?

Comment: No, it is not. It is a part of the type name.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But is there a term for it? A type modifier? Something else?

Comment: Looking for the right term now...

Comment: I don't see a formal name. It is a part of a *declarator* syntax. That is, just a syntax element.

Comment: I concur.  The C specification indicates this  as part of a *declarator.*  It doesn't even call it an asterisk; it simply says "of the form `* type-qualifier-listopt D`".

Comment: That asterisk in a declaration has the same origin as the asterisk in a dereference operator. Per Kernighan and Ritchie 1978, page 90, declarators mimic expressions: `int *p` tells us that, when `*p` appears in an expression, it is an `int`. The declarator gives us a “picture” of an expression, and the asterisk in that picture portrays the dereference operator. But, because the compiler is parsing a declaration, how it interprets the text is different, and, for formal parsing purposes, it is not an operator. But these are technical differences; the common formation still exists.

Comment: In the C++ grammar, the `*` that denotes a pointer being declared is called a *ptr-operator* (which actually covers `*`, `&`, `&&`, and a construct with a *nested-name-specifier*).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486504/clearly-stating-the-difference-betwen-and-as-part-of-a-type-and-as-a-derefer

Answer (score 3):

```
int *p;
```

THAT asterisk is not an operator, it qualifies the type.  "Integer" vs "pointer to integer".

```
int foo;
int *bar = &foo; // not that one

*bar = 4; // THIS one
```

THIS asterisk is an operator... the "dereference operator".  It is used quite a bit for things like smart pointers and iterators.

Same character, different placement, different meaning.

Comment: It is not really accurate to say the asterisk qualifies the type. Grammatically, it qualifies the thing being declared. The fact that the thing being declared is a pointer is then deduced by reversing the grammatical construction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would you say the same thing about `unsigned`?

Comment: Confusingly, my "The C++ Programming Language" (second edition, published in 1991) refers to the-asterisk-in-a-type-declaration as a **declaration operator**.  Whee.

Comment: The difference between `unsigned` and `*` can be seen when you declare multiple variables at once.  Consider `unsigned int *a, b`

Comment: That's hardly confusing at all.  Yet another "Principle of Least Surprise" failure.

Comment: page 94 Kernighan and Ritchie, C programming language states, the unary operator * is the "indirection" or "dereferencing" operator.  When applied to a pointer it accesses the object that the pointer points to.

Comment: @3Dave: `unsigned` and `int` play the same role in `int *p` and `unsigned *p`.

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring a pointer to an int.
example of usage.

```
int x = 1;
int *p;

// you are assigning the address of the int to the pointer
p = &x;

printf( "int %i ptr %i\n", x, *p );
```

Comment: The * notation accesses the object pointed to, the line p = &x, is assigning the address of the integer value to the pointer, so when accessing the value by *p, you can get the actual value that the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score -2):

The comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486599/2725810) puts it so well, I decided to quote it as an answer to my own question (thanks to @bolov to linking!):

> Don't think of `int*` as 2 pieces. It is one thing, it is the "type."
>   (e.g., it would be as if they used an `intp` keyword for the `int` pointer
>   type but the chosen syntax works for all types).

Comment: Unfortunately, the comment is wrong, as can be proven by considering `int *p, a[3], x()`. This declares `p` to be a pointer to an `int`, `a` to be an array of 3 `int`, and `x` to be a function with no arguments that returns an `int`. But there is only one `int`, so it cannot be a single integral piece for all three of them. In fact, in the C++ grammar, `*` and `p` are parsed together, and `int` is separate. After that, in `int *p;`, the `int` is joined with `*p`. In `int *p, a[3], x();`, each item is parsed separately, then formed into a list `*p, a[3], x()`, and only then joined with `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The comment means that your example is equivalent to something  like `intp p; int a[3]; int x()`.

Comment: Showing the list was only used to illustrate the parsing. Separating the items into separate declarations does not change the C++ grammar. In the C++ grammar, specified in the Declarations ([dcl.dcl]) and Declarators ([dcl.decl]) clauses of the C++ standard, the type specifiers (`int`, `unsigned int`, and so on) are separate from the declarators (`*`, `*[]`, and so on). Saying they are one thing, the type, is not an accurate reflection of the C++ standard.